# Track Google map location of user at any point in time using Xamarin Form

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.forms

I am developing Cross Platform Mobile app with Visual Studio Xamarin form and I want to be able to Track Google map location of some specific users of this apps at any point in time. How to go about this?

Comment: https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/signalr

Answer (score 0):

Use james montemagno's GeolocatorPlugin plug-in you have two options one use a timer to hit each interval of time the user position using this

```
var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync (timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);
```

or two suscribe to the locator PositionChanged handle(this will be updated only if the user change his position)

```
var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

    locator.PositionChanged += (o,e) =>{
        var newPosition = e.Position;
}
```

ref:
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Geolocator